# Как Нарисовать полукруги вокруг центра с помощью Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо нарисовать полукруги вокруг центра  с помощью Qt

Цель :Нарисовать один полукруг ,и повернуть его 4 раза

Пытался рисовать так:
    
    `painter.drawChord(QRectF(KV[0],v),0,16*180);
    painter.drawChord(QRectF(KV[1],v),2*16*60-g*4,16*180);
    painter.drawChord(QRectF(KV[2],v),2*16*60-g*2,16*180);
    painter.drawChord(QRectF(KV[3],v),2*16*60-g*4,16*180);
    painter.drawChord(QRectF(KV[4],v),2*16*60-g*4,16*180);`

Вышло
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
да еще и не в центре

Как **должно быть** показано на фото
[image: Как должно получится]

Comment: и в чем вопрос?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Нужно  нарисовать один полукруг ,и повернуть его

Comment: так а вопрос в чем?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Как  нарисовать один полукруг и повернуть его  ,есть ли готовые средства????

Comment: а вы сами пытались хоть что-нибудь сделать? Ну хотя бы гуглили или книгу по qt полистали? Знаете что такое QGraphicsScene?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch сейчас дополню  вопрос.Ну хотя бы гуглили или книгу по qt полистали?-да смотрел

Comment: ну так если смотрели, то что тогда у вас не получается сделать?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch сейчас дополнил ,вот что выходит

Comment: ну так а с чего они должны выстроится в полукруг? Какие прямоугольники вы им задали?

Comment: Прочитайте https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/coordsys.html, там всё есть